# Bug in parsing IFS parameter of while read loop? If not why?

Tags: bash

I have tab-delimited file with some data. I am processing it reading one line at a time into an array. However there are some serious issues with parsing IFS parameter of this command.

This short example below can be reproduced among several bash versions and several systems Windows/cygwin, linux and BSD.

Let's say that I want to print each line with table-like frames (this is NOT relevant - reading is relevant):

```
$ IFS= echo -e "1 2 3\t4 5\t6" | while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a array ; do for field in ${array[@]} ; do echo -n "|  $field  " ; done ; echo "|" ; done
```

Result I'm getting is:

```
|  1  |  2  |  3  |  4  |  5  |  6  |
```

After several tries the only way to get expected behavior is overriding global IFS variable (for the sake of sanity encapsulated in sub-shell):

```
$ echo -e "1 2 3\t4 5\t6" | ( export IFS=$'\t' ; while read -r -a array ; do for num in ${array[@]} ; do echo -n "|  $num  " ; done ; echo "|" ; done )
|  1 2 3  |  4 5  |  6  |
```

The question is: **Why IFS parameter/variable behaves in such weird way? Is there any logic behind it?** - or - Am I missing something?

Comment: `for field in ${array[@]}` string-splits your fields. You need to use `for field in "${array[@]}"` **with the quotes** to preserve boundaries.

Comment: ...which is to say that your parsing is perfectly fine, but you're messing it up on the output end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your script was very nearly correct:

```
$ printf '%s\t' "1 2 3" "4 5" "6" |
> while IFS=$'\t' read -r -a array ; do
>   for field in "${array[@]}" ; do
>     printf '|  %s  ' "$field"
>   done
>   printf '|'
> done
|  1 2 3  |  4 5  |  6  |
```

---

`"${array[@]}"` **must** be quoted to preserve array boundaries accurately.

Comment: Aaaand the award goes here! :) - Thanks a lot, and now everything makes sense - in both examples "for i in ${array[@]}" is the real culprit not the IFS itself. Only difference is that in second example (as for loop has overridden IFS) it properly separates fields in array. Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1):

`IFS` is behaving exactly like it is supposed to. The default `IFS` on almost all Unix-type systems is **'space tab newline'**. Generally seen as:

```
IFS=$' \t\n'
```

In your original case `IFS= echo -e "1 2 3\t4 5\t6"`, you unset `IFS` and then call `echo`. The default is applied breaking on a space. You then expressly set `IFS=$'\t'` which correctly limits field separation/word splitting to the `tab` character and you get the result you want.

Comment: ...but the user _isn't_ seeing the result they want -- they're seeing `| 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6` whereas they expect `| 1 2 3 | 4 5 | 6`, hence the question.

Comment: Now you have me confused. The whole point as I read it was the 'surprise' existed in getting the `| 1 | 2 | 3 |` instead of `| 1 2 3 |` following unsetting `IFS`. The OP obtained the desired results with `IFS=$'\t'`. The questions was "What happened the first time?" and "Is there any logic behind it?" Maybe I'm just getting old :)

Comment: @CharlesDuffy - I see what you are saying and I agree The issue was quoting on the output end. -- and I am getting old.